# Convert JSON Response Returning From Resful Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have these 2 classes in my RESTFUL web service and my web application

```
public class Service
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int HCode { get; set; }
    public int HUserID { get; set; }
    public string PatientNID { get; set; }
    public List<Document> DocumentList { get; set; }
    public int ServiceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public byte[] ByteDocument { get; set; }
}
```

This is the fucntion recieving object and sending back List in web service

```
public List<Serivce> GetServiceByHUserID(Service service)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
              "SELECT *"
            + " FROM TransactionHistory"
            + " WHERE UserID = @HUserUserIDParam"
            , con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
        "@HUserUserIDParam", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = service.HUserID;

        return GetServiceResponse(cmd);
    }

private List<Service> GetServiceResponse(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
            List<Service> serviceList = new List<Service>();
        try
        {
            // Filling Data
              ....
        }
            return serviceList;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { return null; }
        finally { con.Close(); }
    }
```

This is the fucntion sending object and recieving list in web app

```
private List<Service> GetServiceListResponse(HttpWebRequest request
        , Service service)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(service);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = json.Length;
            StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(),
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            requestWriter.Write(json);
            requestWriter.Close();

            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            // ERROR HERE
            dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<List<Service>>(response);
            // ERROR HERE
            responseReader.Close();
            return item;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { return null; }
    }
```

When i try to return List<.Service> as a JSON object and deserialize it i get that error

Here's the exception

> Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use the .NET HttpClient libraries which automatically handle all this for you?

Comment: Its my first time creating a web service so i dont know all the methods of doing it. I might search for that and give it a try. Thank you for your reply. @ErikFunkenbusch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a **SOLUTION**

which is just changing the class that i was using in serializing and deserializing (built in class in .NET called **JavaScriptSerializer**)

From **JavaScriptSerializer**() To **JsonConvert**

Releases on Github: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases

Latest package on NuGut: **Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json**

Newtonsoft website: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

After referencing the dll or downloading the package, reference the dll inside the code (inside the .cs class):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Other references:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
```

Serializing the json object before sending and using **UTF8** Encoding:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(service);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Method = "POSt";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(json);
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), new UTF8Encoding(false));
requestWriter.Write(json);
requestWriter.Close();
```

Deserializing the json object after getting response back:

```
List<Service> serviceList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Service>>(response);
```